# How do you tell is a path is a file or a directory in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

How do I check is a path is a file or a directory?

fileExists(path) tells me if it exists but there doesn't seem to be exposed pipeline that can tell me.  If I create a File object, then I can get fooled as the execution may take place on the agent while the file resides on master or visa versa depending on the execution context

Answer (score 1):

While the solution below the separator works, take a step back and ask... what does knowing something is a directory provide?

In my case, I has a specialized s3BucketManager and want to know when I'm uploading a directory vs a file.  however, in either case this code works

```
def filesToUpload = findFiles(glob: path)
for (def file in filesToUpload) {
   ... do the thing or process the file ...
}
```

I can use size to tell me if I have 1 or many and handle it differently, and in most scenarios, I don't care that the files live in a directory, I just want the files matching a path or glob.

---

Ok this solution probably isn't the best or perhaps even a good solution but it does seem to work.

First, any pipeline code that returns a [FileWrapper](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/pipeline-utility-steps/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/utility/steps/fs/FileWrapper.html) has an isDirectory() method that will tell you.   However, Pipeline findFiles does produce fileWrapper objects but won't find directories.  Which means you can do something like this:

```
boolean isDirectory(def providedPath) {
    // handle case where a File, nio Path, FileWrapper, etc object is passed
    String path = providedPath.toString()


    // Search for this path as a glob - it will find files beneath a dir 
    // and will not report directories
    def files = findFiles(glob: path)

    // check for path found in list then it is a file
    for (def file in files) {
        if ("${file}" == path) {
            return false
        }
    }

    // not found in list therefore it must a directory if it exists
    return fileExists(path)
}
```